# How to add google search in my website?

Tags: google-search

I want to add Google search in my website, so that it will search the pages from only my website and will provide result inside my website page.

I found the google search for websites here: http://www.google.com/sitesearch/ but it seems its paid? is google search fro websites is paid product now? or its available for free?

Please help to clarify doubts about google search for website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/). There are two editions: 1) Standard (Free) and 2) Site Search (Paid).

EDIT:

Here is a link of [Web Search API.](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add a search box that constructs a URL with a site: parameter, such as:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=my_search_string+site:www.slashdot.org

That'll search for 'my_search_string' on slasdot and return the default google page.

The paid-for services let you get out of google ads, customise the results and present them with your own headers and footers etc.

Answer (score 0):

One (definitely free) option is to embed the Google search page using a frame or similar.

```
http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Arushyo.com+stack+overflow
```

Far from ideal though. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

google search is completely free. You can use google custom search. You can find google cse in Google search console